# Merge each person's states in react-slate

Tags: reactjs, express, websocket, react-slate

I am building a doc editor like google doc using react-slate for the frontend and express for the backend. It works well when one person types in the editor but I faced one problem when some people typed in one editor. When two people or some people type the content in one editor, we should merge all the states and show the acceptable result to all people.

How to implement the functionality? on the frontend or backend side?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I only want the guidelines to implement the feature.